# What is the Regex for replacing a character in between two characters in a string in NodeJS? Please see my problem below. Many thanks

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

```
let string = "https://api-staging.data-crypt.com/api/contacts/recents?fromVersionNumber=11324506134&count=1&fields=id%2C2pxnr7agwb%2Cfirstname%2Clastname%2Cleadscore"
```

How do I replace the characters in between 'fromVersionNumber=' and '&' in the string above?

Comment: value between 'fromVersionNumber=' and '&'  can be read and replace using getter setter (getFromVersionNumber and setFromVersionNumber) . try https://regexr.com/ for regex

Comment: @HiteshKumar , how do I used getter and setter in my case?

Comment: I hope this could help you https://javascript.info/property-accessors

Answer (score 2):

Using URL module

https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

```
let string = "https://api-staging.data-crypt.com/api/contacts/recents?fromVersionNumber=11324506134&count=1&fields=id%2C2pxnr7agwb%2Cfirstname%2Clastname%2Cleadscore"

let url = new URL(string)
url.searchParams.set('fromVersionNumber', 123)

console.log(url.toString())
```